# Невстречавший или не встречавший

Tags: частица-не

Что делать со словом "не( )встречавший"?

Если это причастие, то да:

> Людей, не встречавших Бога, называют нормальными.

А если это как бы само существительное:

> Невстречавших нас уволят

Answer (score 1):

Это сочетание может писаться только **раздельно**, поскольку породивший причастие глагол используется *только* в качестве переходного и в законченных высказываниях требует употребления прямого дополнения (*кого, что* встречал). Соответственно, прилагательным, выражающим присущее кому-либо свойство, причастие "встречавший" (здесь с отрицанием) стать не может, как и существительным, которое могло бы возникнуть только через такое прилагательное. Даже с возвратной частицей (не встречающийся, не встречавшийся) подобное причастие не превращается в прилагательное, поскольку не выражает устойчивых свойств чего-либо (кого-либо).

Comment: *Это сочетание может писаться только слитно* — Какое?! "Невстречавший"?!

Comment: Да, сочетание причастия с отрицательной частицей.

Comment: Прокомментировал отдельным ответом. Пока ставлю минус.

Comment: "Раздельно", конечно, я зарапортовался! Аргументы - изначально в пользу этого.

Comment: Бывает :) Я снял минус и удалил свой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Не встречавших нас уволят. Неработающих уволят.**

Написание НЕ определяется по следующему правилу.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80#pp80

2. Пишется раздельно частица не с полными формами причастия, **имеющими при себе пояснительные слова:** не возвращённая автору рукопись; не замеченные корректором опечатки; не сданные в срок гранки; не изданные при жизни писателя варианты отдельных глав романа.

Данное правило распространяется и на причастия, **употребляемые в роли существительных**: В числе **не явившихся на заседание** были Петров и Сергеев.

Но с **субстантивированным причастием** (т. е. при перешедшем в разряд существительных) частица **не пишется слитно**: В классе много неуспевающих по русскому языку.

Пояснение

***Неработающих уволят***. Слитное написание НЕ с причастием при отсутствии зависимых слов. НЕРАБОТАЮЩИЙ, 1. Недействующий, нефункционирующий. Н-ее оборудование. Н-ие законы. 2.  Свободный от работы; лишённый, не имеющий работы (о человеке). Н-ие граждане.

***Не встречавших нас уволят.*** Раздельное написание НЕ с причастием при наличии зависимых слов. **Причастие употребляется в роли существительного в данном тексте, но оно не переходит в разряд существительных**.

Answer (score 0):

> Невстречавших нас уволят

Не очень понятен смысл, местоимение нас к чему относится? Если к "не встречавших" , то это всё тот же причастный оборот, пишется раздельно, слитно может писаться только прилагательное, т.е. обозначать оно должно какой-то постоянный признак, что-то я такого примера никак не найду.  Всё равно подразумевается именно действие встречать кого-то.

Скорее всего, это всё-таки НЕ с причастием и пишется раздельно.

Comment: Мы можем сказать "Людей, которые нас не встречали, уволят". Здесь мы заменим "которые нас не встречали" на "невстречавших". 
Или другой вариант "Неработающих уволят". Как бы если есть определяемое слово - "Не работающих людей", то да, раздельно. Но если слова нет, я думаю, надо слитно писать...

Comment: Вы путаете определяемое слово и зависимое. Не встречавших ( кого?) нас - есть зависимое слово, пишем раздельно. Работающих поощрят, неработающих уволят - зависимого слова нет, определяемого (людей) тоже нет, неработающих можно заменить синонимом без НЕ - прилагательными ленивых, прохлаждающихся или существительным тунеядцев, значит, слитно.